# Divide two dataframes with groupby in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to figure out how to divide two columns from different datasets, grouping by a common key, in order to obtain a percentage.

Table 1

```
 Index   ID        sum
    0   100001      7
    1   100002      8
    2   100003      4
```

Table 2

```
     Index    ID   TYPE     sum
        0   100001  A        7    
        1   100002  A        4    
        2   100002  B        4   
        3   100003  A        2    
        4   100003  B        2
```

I want to divide the variable `sum` from `table 1` by `sum` from `table 2`, grouping by `ID` and `TYPE`.

The goal is to obtain the table bellow, which represents the percentage of `sum` by `TYPE` and `ID`.

Table 3

```
  Index  ID   TYPE  sum_percent
    0   100001  A     1.0
    1   100002  A     0.5
    2   100002  B     0.5
    3   100003  A     0.5
    4   100003  B     0.5
```

I was trying some codes to achieve this question, like this one bellow but it throws an error message. It seems that the problem is in the `groupby` statement.

```
`table_1[['sum']].groupby('ID')/table_2[['sum']].groupby('ID')`
```

Comment: aaannndd, have you tried anything? You know that SO is not a service to do your job.

Comment: Of course I had! I thought it would unnecessary to say that in the post. Anyway, I edited my post stating what I tried. I'm kind new to Python and I'm trying to learning it

Comment: Sorry, are you using Pandas? The `group-by` tag refers to SQL, there's a separate tag for Pandas's groupby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need `groupby`; your operation is closer to a `merge`. In this case, you can create a series mapping from `table1`:

```
s = table1.set_index('ID')['sum']
```

Then use this for your calculation in `table2`:

```
table2['sum_percent'] = table2['sum'] / table2['ID'].map(s)
```